Twilio playing only white noise while trying to stream audio
I am trying to stream audio generated by ElevenLabs (via their websocket) back to Twilio. However, I was only able to hear white noise.
However, when I used their API to get the audio, opened it, and streamed it to twilio, it was played on the phone properly.
Below is my code where I'm trying to generate audio from elevenlabs, and then sending it to my twilio socket
async def text_to_speech_stream(text: str):
    voice_id = "pNInz6obpgDQGcFmaJgB"
    model_id = "eleven_multilingual_v2"

    # Construct the WebSocket URL
    url = f"wss://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/{voice_id}/stream-input?model_id={model_id}"

    # Set up headers
    headers = {
        'xi-api-key': ""
    }

    # Payload to send
    payload = {
        "text": " ",
        "voice_settings": {
            "stability": 0.0,
            "similarity_boost": 1.0,
            "style": 0.0,
            "use_speaker_boost": True
        },
        "model_id": model_id,
        "voice_id": voice_id,
        "xi-api-key": "",
        "output_format": "ulaw_8000",
        "flush":True
    }

    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        print("websocket connected: 11labs")
        # Send the payload as JSON
        await ws.send(json.dumps(payload))
        await ws.send(json.dumps({"text":text}))
        await ws.send(json.dumps({"text": ""}))

        # Receive audio chunks
        start_time = time.time()
        print("waiting for revecivng")
        print()
        audio_buffer = bytearray()
        while True:
            try:
                message = await ws.recv()
                data = json.loads(message)
                if data.get("audio"):
                    # Audio chunk received
                    print("yielded in: ",time.time()-start_time, flush=True)

                    yield data["audio"]#base64.b64decode(data["audio"])
                    
                elif data.get('isFinal'):
                    break

                elif isinstance(message, str):
                    # Text message received (e.g., errors or status updates)
                    data = json.loads(message)
                    if data.get("warning"):
                        print(f"Warning: {data['warning']}")
                    elif data.get("error"):
                        print(f"Error: {data['error']}")
                        break
                    else:
                        print(f"Message from ElevenLabs: ")
                else:
                    print("Unknown message type received")
            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK:
                # Connection closed gracefully
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in ElevenLabs WebSocket: {e}")
                break


async def send_to_twilio_eleven(websocket, message, stream_sid, interruption_event):
    print("Starting TTS streaming from ElevenLabs")
    try:
        start_time = time.time()
        print("message is: ", message)
        audio_payload = ""
        count = 0
        # audio_payload = text_to_speech_stream(message) # for API

        async for audio_chunk in text_to_speech_stream(message):
            print("Chunk yielded in : ",time.time()-start_time)
            # Trying to buffer. Facing same issue even when streamed directly without buffering
            audio_payload += audio_chunk

            # Construct the message to send to Twilio
            audio_delta = {
                "event": "media",
                "streamSid": stream_sid,
                "media": {
                    "payload": audio_payload
                }
            }

            # ideal for sending chunks
            if interruption_event.is_set():
                print("Interruption detected")
                return

            # Send the message to Twilio
            await websocket.send_json(audio_delta)
            print("received audio sent to twilio")

            # Yield control to the event loop
            await asyncio.sleep(0)


    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in send_to_twilio_eleven: {e}")

Is there anything I am doing wrong while receiving the audio from ElevenLabs or before sending it to twilio?

The solution 11labs suggested is to adding the output_format as a query param in the websocket url.
wss://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/${VOICE_ID}/stream-input?model_id=${ELEVENLABS_MODEL_ID}&output_format=ulaw_8000&inactivity_timeout=180

